# @Command/@Function to replicate the menu command Create-Picture option in code

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, hcl-notes

I think the title explains the question but what I am asking is if there is a Function / @Command / LotusScript option to perform the same process as the Create-Picture function in the client?

Answer (score 2):

In formula this would be:

```
@Command( [FileImport] ; "JPEG Image" ; "C:\Path\yourimage.jpg" )
```

You can also use "BMP Image" or "GIF Image" as Type.

Excerpt from Designer Help:

> **FileImport @Command**
> Imports a file into a Notes/Domino document or view.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> @Command( [FileImport] ; fileType ; fileName )
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *fileType*
>
> Text. The kind of file you want to import. See list of file types, below.
>
> *fileName*
>
> Text. The name of the file you want to import. Must be a complete path specification, including drive, directory, and file name.